# Less in Jetbrains: Nonshortand property width has shortthand value

Tags: css, less, phpstorm

I caught this warning under a less file under PHPStorm IDE:

`Nonshortand property width has shortthand value`

The problem code is below:

```
@body-width: 1000px;

.block-posts {
  width: @body-width*0.5-25px;
}
```

Well, I see that should be a warning, that `@body-width` has a dash separator, and it take ambiguity into that sentence, which makes arithmetic operates on it.

Add I checked the style of less on the official site: http://lesscss.org/

It seems using a dash sign in a variable name is widely acceptable.

So how to adapt my code style to fix this warning?

And what do this warning exactly means?

Please help.

Comment: This warning is meant for CSS code (where this would be a wrong `width` value of course) and it has nothing to do with `-` in the variable name. It seems that PHPStorm tries to lint Less files as CSS but this does not really make sense in a general case (so I would definitely turn such linting off, assuming the IDE provides corresponding option somewhere).

Comment: no warnings are shown for me on this code in WebStorm 9. What version do you work with? Does the problem persist after invalidating caches (File/Invalidate caches, restart)?

Comment: @lena PyCharm 4.0.2 with less extension

Comment: works fine for me in PyCharm with bundled LESS plugin. Did you try invalidating caches?